# Find lines that end with a particular letter

Tags: linux, shell-script

How to grep for lines that end with a letter `a or d` followed by `xy` 
I know that using $ you can check for the ending but not sure how to combine this 
and use or condition

Answer (score 0):

Few commands to match lines ending with `axy` or `dxy`:

```
# pick one
grep   'axy$\|dxy$'
grep -E 'axy$|dxy$'
grep  '\(a\|d\)xy$'
grep -E  '(a|d)xy$'
```

- You are right about `$`, it matches the end of the line.
- `|` is "or". You need to escape it (with `\`) in BRE (basic regular expression); without escaping the character is literal. In ERE (extended regular expression, `grep -E`) it's the other way around: "or" when not escaped, literal when escaped.
- `(` and `)` indicate a group, here I used them to limit the scope of `|`. Similarly, you need to escape in BRE, you mustn't escape in ERE.